# Classic ASP on IIS7 ==> application pool managed pipeline mode "integrated" or "classic"?

Tags: memory, iis-7, asp-classic, application-pool, integrated-pipeline-mode

On IIS7, does the managed pipeline mode setting for an application pool influence memory consumption behavior of classic ASP web applications?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know yes, classical mode needs more memory and I ran myself into trouble using classical mode when I use .NET com visible components. Integrated mode works always fine for me.